# ABAP GUI_DOWNLOAD issue where characters turned to decimal format E+

Tags: excel, download, format, abap

Program is using GUI_DOWNLOAD then save to excel file.

But upon opening the excel file, some cells which is expected to have sample value "1E9" is turned into data "1000000000" or "1.00E+09".

[Sample comparison between excel & (screenshot) SAP screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4MNW.jpg)

Turns out any variable with data type char3 with this format number + E + number is converted into an actual number.

Is there any way to fix this issue so that the downloaded version shows the ACTUAL expected data (i.e. 1E9 from sample given)?

The quick fix would be just to manipulate the excel file's format.
But is there any way to do have a fix programmatically to reduce manual work?

(Of course, aside from creating a new variable of char(4) and adding character ' in front.

Thanks very much! =]!

Comment: Are you downloading a native Excel file or a CSV text file?

Comment: @pnuts : It is a necessary setup. As much as possible we'd like to retain using that format for some... entries. =]

Comment: @vwegert : excel file. I've actually tried downloading it as CSV file but when I tried opening the .csv file to excel, it still has the same behavior/issue. Also we prefer it in excel. =]

Comment: @pnuts : I see. Though, it's still not a good option to propose to just change all of those data with format nEn...

Comment: _Of course, aside from creating a new variable of char(4) and adding character ' in front_

What is wrong with that? The problem is in the interpretation of the data in Excel. Adding the back tick tells it it is a text field.

Comment: @GertBeukema : Well, i previously encountered an issue where they wanted to remove the 'extra' character/s. Users are going to eventually extract those data from the downloaded excel files and process them somewhere else, by batch.

Comment: if this cell format is excel default, one either could try to deactivate this ( treat all cells of specific columns as string , do not know how in abap, at least vbs would be involved later) or programatically surround the problematic values with any kind of deli,iters, like ", '' , or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you investigate the OLE objects in ABAP. Rather than downloading a csv file, and giving the extension .xls/.xlsx, actually build an Excel file, then call Excel's 'Save As' method to save the file to disk.

See this link for some help:
http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Sample+program+to+open+excel+sheet+using+OLE